# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error using JS

Tags: javascript, api

Error:
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Here is the getJSON call

```
var fewd = {
  getJSON: function(url, success) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        success(json);
      }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.send();
  },
};
```

What should be added here to fix this issue. I read through all the previous bugs but cannot figure out exactly what should be added here.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can add here to fix it but what you have to do is find a way to not send that head in http request via `url`. Either by configuring your server or finding a service that does this.

Research CORS

Comment: Any recommendations to fix this ?

Comment: make server send the right headers...http://enable-cors.org/server.html ..... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields